# fuelsdk row limit on batch delete and retrieval

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, dataextensions

Is there a limit on amount of rows that can be retrieved or deleted on a given request?
I seem to keep hitting around 2500 rows when I have nearly double that in the dataextension.
This seems to happen on a GET request and a DELETE.
However, this does not hinder the ability to add rows in batch. 
I can easily add 7,000+ rows in a batch POST.

Comment: Are you getting back a response "MoreDataAvailable"?  I know you can only retrieve 2500 at a time, not sure about Delete.  This might be helpful...http://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/retrieving-more-than-2500-records-using-the-continuerequest-property.html

Comment: I'm using the python fuelsdk. I see there is a "more_results" response, but unlike the other language implementations, I am not seeing a "continue_request".

Comment: Is this only implemented in the SOAP client?

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct request for this... Unfortunately, it was a matter of not reading far enough into the repo docs.

In Python:

```
# Retrieve lots of rows with moreResults
print '>>> Retrieve lots of rows with moreResults'
row = ET_Client.ET_DataExtension_Row()
row.auth_stub = stubObj
row.Name = "zipstolong"
row.props = ["zip","latitude","longitude"]
getResponse = row.get()
print 'Retrieve Status: ' + str(getResponse.status)
print 'Code: ' + str(getResponse.code)
print 'Message: ' + str(getResponse.message)
print 'MoreResults: ' + str(getResponse.more_results)
print 'RequestID: ' + str(getResponse.request_id)
print 'Results Length: ' + str(len(getResponse.results))
#print 'Results: ' + str(getResponse.results)

while getResponse.more_results: 
    print '>>> Continue Retrieve lots of rows with moreResults'
    getResponse = row.getMoreResults()
    print 'Retrieve Status: ' + str(getResponse.status)
    print 'Code: ' + str(getResponse.code)
    print 'Message: ' + str(getResponse.message)
    print 'MoreResults: ' + str(getResponse.more_results)
    print 'RequestID: ' + str(getResponse.request_id)
    print 'Results Length: ' + str(len(getResponse.results))
```